# Api route that sends local server file upon failure

Tags: express

I'm trying to setup a route that does a node-fetch from a third party API to send back info to the client.

I was wondering if its possible to set it up so that if the third party API fails, the server defaults to a localized file it sends to the client?

```ts
routes.get("/data", async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");

    const data = await fetch("https://api.blahblah.com/files");

    const jsndata = await data.json();

    const formatData = jsndata.filter((item: { fork: boolean }) => {
      return item.fork === false;
    });

    res.send(formatData);
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    if (err === 400) {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(localData));
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Just add a check for `if (data.ok) { ... }` right after the `const data = await fetch(...)` to detect non-200 statuses.  Other than that, I can't tell what you're really asking for here.  And, your `catch` logic needs fixing because `err` will be an Error object, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property and if it is `false`, respond with your local file.

For example

```ts
routes.get("/data", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-store");

    const response = await fetch("https://api.blahblah.com/files");
    if (!response.ok) {
      return res.json(localData); // respond with local data
    }

    const jsndata = await response.json();

    const formatData = jsndata.filter((item: { fork: boolean }) => {
      return item.fork === false;
    });

    res.json(formatData);
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```